# Populating View from db

Tags: apache-flex, flex-mobile

Community!

I have selection Views, based on lists, that the user can select. Ultimately, they reach they're final selection which brings them to a View that is always the same, but populated with information from db (sqlite at the moment, but I'm willing to go xml).

**Problem:**

How can I reuse the same View and populate it with the db info based on user selection/input?

I don't need code, just some architectural suggestions/guidance about how I can reuse a single view to handle whatever requests come across it.

I'm aware this might seem very broad, so questions might help me narrow this down.

Thanks for any input.

**EDIT 1**

My application is basically a number of lists, all populated by the same db.

IE. View1 = list1, user makes selection, goto View2 = list2 (same db), and then user makes selection, goto COMMONView (same end-view for all selection paths) - populated by db information based on selections.

So - Now the question is two-fold:

1) How to keep a connection open across multiple views?

2) How to populate the end-view from information from the db?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to 1) get data from the server or 2) keep adding those results to a single instance of some widget?

1) is the user-initiated event the question?  or how to retrieve data from the server?

2) a trivial way would be to have a single collection declared as [Bindable] in some central location, and have it be the data-provider to your widget(s).

If I'm hitting close to the mark, let me know and i'll try to get closer.

Comment: Thanks for the input @digasse. I'm looking for something closer to #2. 
I want my application to be a number of lists, all populated by a db. IE. View1 = list1, user makes selection, goto View2 = list2 (same db), and then user makes selection, goto COMMONView (same end-view for all selection paths) - populated by db information.